why produces parameter expecting in request mapping in spring boot 3.2.5
In spring boot 3.1.5 if we don't add produces parameter also returning response but after updating spring boot version to 3.2.5 then here request mapping expecting produces parameter . Can any one answer this why produces parameter expecting latest spring boot?

It isn't expected nor required so there must be something else going on.
